# How to implement an Iterator where the associated type Item is a slice?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a `Combination` struct and I need to implement `Iterator` for it. The trait requires defining the associated type `Item` and I need to define it as slice `&[usize]`.

If I write this:

```
pub struct Combination {
    n: usize,
    k: usize,
    comb: Vec<usize>,
}

impl Iterator for Combination {
    type Item = &[usize];
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&[usize]> {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:9:17
  |
9 |     type Item = &[usize];
  |                 ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

If I specify a lifetime:

```
impl<'a> Iterator for Combination {
    type Item = &'a [usize];
```

This makes me add a lifetime specifier to `Combination` even if it doesn't need any lifetimes:

```
pub struct Combination<'a> {
```

Next, compiler gives the error that lifetime `'a` is never used, and I have to add a `PhantomData` field:

```
pub struct Combination<'a> {
    n: usize,
    k: usize,
    comb: Vec<usize>,
    pd: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a [usize]>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Combination<'a> {
    type Item = &'a [usize];
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&[usize]> {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

It compiles, but looks like a kludge. Is there better solution?

Comment: *but looks like a kludge* — it won't even compile if you try to implement the body, so this isn't even a solution.

Comment: No errors related to lifetimes, I meant.
`fn next`'s argument must be `&mut self`, not `&self`, and if I just return None it compiles. Apart from some warnings.

Comment: And `fn next`'s return type must be `Option<&'a [usize]>` of course

Comment: Yes, @Shepmaster, you're right, it doesn't compile when I try to return `Some(&self.comb)`. I need StreamingIterator or something else.